# Calculate the mean and variance by element by element of multiple arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, mean, variance

I have a block of code that provides five arrays:

```
for i in range(10):
    x = pic[10,15+i]
```

This produces the following ten arrays:

```
[504 591 471 ...   0   0   0]
[748 753 658 ...  94 138 101]
[814 781 710 ...   0   0   0]
[754 719 663 ...   0   0   0]
[1068  982 1096 ...    0    0    0]
[845 811 709 ...   0   0   0]
[1002  985  915 ...    0    0    0]
[1036  916  860 ...    0    0    0]
[570 623 722 ...   0   0   0]
[728 711 738 ...   0   0  90]
```

There are 1220 elements in each arrays which are presented by ... . I want to calculate the mean of those 10 arrays by element by element (column wise). So, I want a final output like this:

```
[860.9, 827.4, 795.3, ...  9.4, 13.8, 19.1]
```

I am not getting how to do it in Python. Any help would be highly appreciated. Also, if you can help me calculate the variance as well it would be an amazing help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using zip function:-**

**Code:-**

```
import statistics
#Using package statistics :- Variance
#Using Zip function -: mean
lis=[[22,23,20,32,45,0],
     [25,23,20,33,39,0],
     [26,23,26,31,56,0],
     [28,23,26,0,11,0],
     [25,34,25,0,0,0]]
mean=[]
variance=[]
for i in zip(*lis):
    mean.append(sum(i)/len(i))
    variance.append(statistics.variance(i))
print(mean)
print(variance)
```

**Output:-**

```
[25.2, 25.2, 23.4, 19.2, 30.2, 0.0]
[4.7, 24.2, 9.8, 307.7, 560.7, 0]
```

**Updated:-**
Query-
Try this Don't know is it working or not please let me know..

```
x=[]
mean=[]
variance=[]
for i in range(10):
    x.append(pic[10,15+i])

for i in zip(*x):
    mean.append(sum(i)/len(i))
    length=len(i)
    x=sum(i)/length  #x is also a mean
    variance.append(sum((j - x) ** 2 for j in i)/(length-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use numpy as following:
Create an array that stores the 5 arrays, and then use the numpy.mean() function:

```
import numpy as np

arrays = [
[22, 23, 20, 32, 45, 0],
[25, 23, 20, 33, 39, 0],
[26, 23, 26, 31, 56, 0],
[28, 23, 26, 0, 11, 0],
[25, 34, 25, 0, 0, 0]]

mean = np.mean(arrays, axis=0)
variance = np.variance(arrays, axis=0)
```

The axis specifies that you want to calculate the mean column wise and not row wise.

Comment: Hi thank you for reply! Is there any way to store the arrays after the for loop without doing it manually? Because the array provides 1225 element which are being presented by ..., also I might have to run the for loop for 10-20 pixel values which will return around 10-20 arrays. It's kind of impossible to store the arrays manually.

Comment: The above code uses no loop. The mean array contains all the mean values element wise and the variance array contains all the element wise variances. And you could add those 10-20 arrays to the ‘arrays‘ array with arrays.append(array). So if you have the 10-20 arrays you don’t have to do any manual work here.

Comment: So, if you look at the for i in range(5): x = pic[10,15+i]; it's providing 5 different arrays. I tried to append it using arrays.append(array). But it's giving me this error "numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'"

Comment: Can you kindly help me how to append the numpy arrays?

Comment: Numpy‘s append works differently as the arrays are immutable. So new_arr = np.append(old_arr, add_arr) you can look at the numpy documentation for more info on that function.